# Tinymce - replace textcontent with custom plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a custom plugin to change english digits to persian in all of text content.`123`=>`۱۲۳`

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('fanumber', function (editor, url) {
            var faNumber = function () {
                var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
                var startNode = ed.selection.getNode();
                var walker = new tinymce.dom.TreeWalker(startNode);
                do {
                    var currnet = walker.current().textContent;
                    if (isHTML(currnet) === false) {
                        walker.current().textContent = currnet.toFaDigit();
                    }
                } while (walker.next());
            };
            editor.ui.registry.addButton('fanumber', {
                text: 'ف',
                onAction: function () {
                    faNumber();
                }
            });
            function isHTML(str) {
                var html = $("<div />").append(str).get(0);
                for (var i = 0; i < html.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    if (html.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But not work correctly and corrupts html codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this simple way and work fine :|

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('fanumber', function (editor, url) {
    var faNumber = function () {
        var content = editor.getContent();
        var html = $('<div></div>').append(content);
        $(html).find('*').contents().filter(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '') {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.toFaDigit();
            }
        });
        editor.setContent($(html)[0].innerHTML);
    };
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('fanumber', {
        text: 'ف',
        onAction: function () {
            faNumber();
        }
    });
   
});
```